# Redux Filtering Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I've read similar questions but I still cannot figure out. When I typing, it filters out the items on the screen but if I delete a character in the search box, it does not show previous items. For example, I type "ab" it shows all product names that start with "ab", however, when I delete "b" or "ab" it does not show the products, just a blank page.

Search

```
class Search extends Component {
  handleChange = e => {
    this.props.search(e.target.value);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Input
          type="search"
          name="search"
          placeholder="Search"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value={this.props.value}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  value: state.value
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { search })(Search);
```

Action

```
export const search = value => ({
  type: SEARCH,
  payload: value
});
```

Reducer

```
export const Products = (
  state = {
    products: [],
    comments: [],
    value: ''
  },
  action
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    ...
    case 'SEARCH':
      return {
        ...state,
        value: action.payload,
        products: state.products.filter(product => product.name.includes(action.payload))
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: you shouldn't write your filter function in your reducer, your reducer should be pure and shouldn't change your state, this cause loses your original data. you have to map your store to props in your component and in-class lifecycle manipulate your desire change (like a filter that you did in reducer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you filter you are updating `products` in your state, so each consecutive search is performed on the previously filtered value. In other words, you are losing the original copy of your `products` array.

You only need to store the search value, and then any component which subscribes to `products` can derive the filtered products from the search value. For example:

```
class Example extends Component {
  render() {
    const filteredProducts = this.props.products.filter(product =>
      product.name.includes(this.props.value)
    );
    return filteredProducts.map(product => ...)
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  value: state.value,
  products: state.products,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { search })(Example);
```

Comment: But I definitely don't want to render my filtered products in the search component. There must be a way to fix this with Redux.

Comment: The way to fix it with Redux is to store an original copy and a filtered copy, but you would be storing unnecessary state which can be derived. The more you can keep out of Redux the better.

The example is just demonstrating how you might access the filtered products from the Search component, but it can be any component which you connect.

Comment: It still doesn't make sense to me. I am looking for another solution, for example my Products component gets products from the Main component as a prop and when I connect the Products component, it will mess up. This way doesn't seem reusable.

Comment: Your products are coming from Redux somewhere, so the solution is to derive the filtered products at the component level. If your Main component is subscribing to `products`, you should be able to filter there before passing them down. If you insist on keeping everything inside Redux (which is not recommended), I said above that you would need to maintain two sets of products in your store: `products` and `filteredProducts`, where `products` is the original unfiltered array of products.

Comment: Even though the root cause is pointed out correctly (unnecessary filtering source array within state upon search), I wouldn't say maintaining two copies of the same data (full and filtered) is the best way out. I'd say, it'd be better to filter your product list component based on what is searched as you update search string within the store.

Comment: Yes, filtering at the component-level is exactly what I described above